# vue.js / v-for: How to style html depending on list index

Tags: html, list, vue.js, indexing, v-for

I have a list, of which I want to style the items in a different way, depending on their indexes:

```
<ul>
    <li 
    v-for="(item, index) in myList()" 
    :key="index">{{item}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

If `item` reaches index 4 and 5, I want it to be `<strong>`. How do I use `v-if` or `indexof` in this case the right way?

Or should I go with dynamic classes in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

### 1. Bind a method that returns an object to the `style` attribute

You can do this by binding the `<li>` element's `style` attribute to a method that accepts its index. In the method, you return a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object that is appropriate. For example, if `i` is 4 or 5, then you set `fontWeight` to bold:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    myList: function() {
      return ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolor', 'Sit', 'Amet', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
    },
    listItemStyle: function(i) {
      var style = {};
      
      if (i === 4 || i === 5) {
        style.fontWeight = 'bold';
      }
      
      return style;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="(item, index) in myList()"
      :style="listItemStyle(index)"
      :key="index">
      {{item}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### 2. Use `<component>` to determine if a `<strong>` tag should be rendered

This is not my preferred method, since I personally prefer binding styles instead of dictating appearance using DOM elements. However, if you want to use `<strong>` instead of setting `font-weight: bold`, you can simply make use of the `<component is="[tag]">` method to decide which HTML tag to be rendered in place:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    myList: function() {
      return ['Lorem', 'Ipsum', 'Dolor', 'Sit', 'Amet', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'];
    },
    tag: function(i) {
      if (i === 4 || i === 5) {
        return 'strong';
      }
      
      return 'span';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="(item, index) in myList()"
      :key="index">
      <component v-bind:is="tag(index)">
        {{item}}
      </component>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx, I like the second approach :-)